# Origins of $\frac1{r^2\sin(\theta)}$ term for curl of vector field in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, change-of-variable, curl, curvilinear-coordinates

The curl of a vector field $\vec A$ in spherical coordinates is given by
$$\nabla \times \overrightarrow{\mathrm{A}}=\frac{1}{r^{2} \sin \theta} \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\widehat{a}_{\mathrm{r}} & r \widehat{\mathrm{a}}_{\theta} & \operatorname{rsin} \theta \widehat{\mathrm{a}}_{\phi} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\
\mathrm{A}_{\mathrm{r}} & \mathrm{rA}_{\theta} & \mathrm{r} \sin \theta \mathrm{A}_{\phi}
\end{array}\right|$$

Source [here](https://www.therightgate.com/deriving-curl-in-cylindrical-and-spherical/), screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY6R3.png).

What is the mathematical reasoning behind the $\frac{1}{r^2sin\theta}$ when finding the curl of a vector in spherical coordinates? How would we derive it?

Comment: @K.defaoite unfortunately OP is asking about spherical coordinates, for which I am unable to find an equivalent link. to OP: the derivation in the answer there works also for spherical coordinates, but you have to of course change the specific details from cylindrical to spherical. Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013153/finding-curl-in-spherical-coordinates?rq=1)

Comment: This youtube video along with the explanation from the other post resolved my confusion, but will take a bit of time to digest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw3zDVeUAEg